# ending a call when someone calls

Tags: android

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
context.startService(new Intent(context,MyPhoneStateListener.class));    
MyPhoneStateListener lst=new MyPhoneStateListener(context); 
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);   
telephonyManager.listen(lst, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE); 
} 

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
 { // TODO Auto-generated method stub return null; 

} 
}

   // class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
{ 
  //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged"; 
   Context context; 
  //Context to make Toast if required 
  public MyPhoneStateListener(Context context) 
  { 
  super(); 
  this.context = context; 
  } 

 @Override 
 public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {  
 super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber); 

 switch (state)
  { 
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE: //when Idle i.e no call 
  Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Idle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   break; 
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK: //when Off hook i.e in call //Make intent and start your service here Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Off hook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
   break; 
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING: //when Ringing Toast.makeText(context, "Phone state Ringing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   break; 
  default: break; 
 } } }
```

want to develop a application that ends a call when a user calls , first it should detect from the databases whether that number is stored or not. which would be better idea. to use services or broadcast receiver.to end the call please help with the code i have been trying out for the last one week. i used broadcast receiver but that didnot help as when the call cums in ,other activity strts except for the receiver.

Comment: Who is going to come and edit your question my dear friend.

Comment: Do you want to drop an outgoing call when the dialled number is not in your list?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to drop an outgoing call in case the called number is not in a list:

You need to register a receiver in your manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:exported="true"
        android:name=".receiver.OutgoingCall" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="0" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Then follow [this](http://code.google.com/p/unlocking-android/source/browse/chapter7/trunk/src/com/msi/manning/telephonyexplorer/OutgoingCallReceiver.java?spec=svn78&r=78)